# Python While Loop- Addition between two numbers

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop, addition

Essentially, if the user inputs 2,12, the output should be 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 9 + 10 + 11 + 12.

```
num1 = int(input("Please enter a number between 1 and 10: "))
num2 = int(input("Please enter a number between 11 and 20: "))
addition = num1 + num2
print (addition)
sum = 0
count = 1

while (count <= num1):
   sum = sum + 1
   count = count + 1


print ("Your total price comes to ", total_price)
```

Comment: Do you want python or c++ code?

Comment: this is the example of the end result of the program,

Comment: Please enter any number between 1 and 10: 10

Please enter any number between 11 and 20: 13

The sum of all the numbers between 10 and 13 is: 46

Comment: _"Please enter any number between 1 and 10:"_ No, I won't. Kick-ass: Go improve your question and make your problems clear there. Sorry if I'm getting rude, tired already for today, good night.

Comment: Whats wrong with my question?

Comment: What's your actual problem

Comment: Can you use for ? its very easy with for loop.

Comment: My problem is i dont know the code to add up all the numbers between the 2 user inputs shown above.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Let me try to clarify:

If the user inputs 1, 4 (I know this doesn't meet the requirements, but bear with me as we try to figure out what you're even asking), is the result supposed to be 1+2+3+4?

Comment: No, this is what I'm asking, if the user inputs any number from 1 -10 and then inputs any number from 11-20, for example, 2,12 then it requires the sum of all the numbers in between 2 and 12. this is what i actually mean

Comment: @mrphy123 That's still unclear to me. Would 2,12 return 3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+11?

Comment: 2,12 = 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 9 + 10 + 11 + 12

Comment: num1 = int(input("Please enter a number between 1 and 10: "))                         
                                                                                                            num2 = int(input("Please enter a number between 11 and 20: "))
                                                                                                               res= 0
for i in range(num1,(num2+1)):
    res+=i
print ("Your total price comes to ",res)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
num1 = int(input("Please enter a number between 1 and 10: "))
num2 = int(input("Please enter a number between 11 and 20: "))
the_sum = 0

start = num1
end = num2 + 1

m = start
while m  < end:
    the_sum += m
    m += 1

print ("Your total price comes to ", the_sum)
```

Comment: Instead of `sum_`, use something else like `the_sum`

Comment: @PythonMaster - Thanks for pointing this out, I have modified it.

Comment: @PythonMaster - Thanks for pointing this out, I have modified it.

Comment: thanks for that but its giving me a different answer, also can we do it in "while" loop?

Comment: @mrphy123 - I have updated the answer.

Comment: May God bless you. You really helped me, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems... including that you are not actually doing anything. All you really do is do the `addition` line and printing what it is. Naturally, you should start with a `for` loop that will loop through the limits set by the user:

```
for i in range(num1, (num2)+1):
```

Now to add the numbers in between and keep track of the current sum, let's create two variables to keep track:

```
current_sum = 0
number = num1
for i in range(num1, (num2)+1):
```

Now add `number` to `current_score` and add one to `number`:

```
current_sum = 0
number = num1
for i in range(num1, (num2)+1):
    current_score += number
    number += 1
```

Then finally print the result:

```
current_sum = 0
number = num1
for i in range(num1, (num2)+1):
    current_score += number
    number += 1
print current_sum
```

Comment: can we do it through while loop, instead of "for"?